# Changing the Compose Key in KDE

Tags: keyboard, kde, compose-key

So I have become accustomed to Ubuntu's compose key setup. You press <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and then a sequence of characters (eg: <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>)and something magical happens: ß

This doesn't appear to work the same in KDE/Kubuntu. This is a problem because I love it. I have two problems:

- The mapping appears to have changed to <kbd>Right Super</kbd>. I want the original mapping. The dialogue (under Keyboard settings > Advanced) does not offer a combination.
- <strike>I can't do fancy arrows with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd></strike> **Edit:** I *can* do fancy arrows, the combo has just changed to <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> and I have to hold the compose key. →... Hmm but I can't do left arrows. Oh this is making my face ache.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using OpenSuse with KDE, and was having a similar problem. Found my answer here: http://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey/en#Current_KDE_Configuration. I've managed to get altgr to be compose, and ß and ← and → work fine for me.

That is:

[image]

- Start *System Settings*
- Select *Input Devices* then *Keyboard*
- Click the *Advanced* tab
- Click the box next to *Configure Keyboard Options* to enable changing keyboard options
- Click the `>` icon next to *Position of Compose* key to show drop-down options
- Click the box next to the desired key to enable it.